# Stacking ReLU RBM into a DBN

Tags: python, rbm, dbn

I'm implementing a Restricted Boltzmann Machine with Rectified Linear Units. I haven't found a simple implementation anywhere so wanted to ask if somebody would kindly verify the design.

Here is the CD1 calculation:

```
def propup(self, vis):
    activation = numpy.dot(vis, self.W) + self.hbias        
    # ReLU activation of hidden units
    return activation * (activation > 0)

def sample_h_given_v(self, v0_sample):
    h1_mean = self.propup(v0_sample)
    # Sampling from a rectified Normal distribution
    h1_sample = numpy.maximum(0, h1_mean + numpy.random.normal(0, sigmoid(h1_mean)))
    return [h1_mean, h1_sample]

def propdown(self, hid):
    activation = numpy.dot(hid, self.W.T) + self.vbias
    return sigmoid(activation)

def sample_v_given_h(self, h0_sample):
    v1_mean = self.propdown(h0_sample)
    v1_sample = self.numpy_rng.binomial(size=v1_mean.shape, n=1, p=v1_mean)
    return [v1_mean, v1_sample]
```

This is how I calculate the gradient:

```
def get_cost_updates(self, lr, decay, mom, l1_penalty, p_noise, epoch, persistent=None, k=1):
    ph_mean, ph_sample = self.sample_h_given_v(input)
    nv_means, nv_samples,nh_means, nh_samples = self.gibbs_hvh(ph_sample)      

    W_grad = numpy.dot(self.input.T, ph_mean) - numpy.dot(nv_samples.T, nh_means)
    vbias_grad = numpy.mean(self.input - nv_samples, axis=0)
    hbias_grad = numpy.mean(ph_mean - nh_means, axis=0)
```

My question is, how do I layer these into a DBN?

The aim is to construct an autoencoder, but I'm not sure how to handle the visible units also being real number variables in the second layer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that question was asked some time ago, but as there is no answer, I will add mine.
DBN as you wrote is implemented with a greedy learning algorithm that takes each layer to be as if it is a RBM. I actually gave a lecture about it recently and you can find a presentation with a numeric example I used here:https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/AvnerGidron/generative-models/AvnerGidron/generative-models

I think that if you will understand the presentation it shouldn't take really long for you to do it yourself.